# Fill NA while keeping continous scale

Tags: r, na, fill

I'd like to know if there's a way to fill NA values while keeping a continuous scale for a numeric vector.

Suppose I have a vector like this:

```
set.seed(55)
as.list(missForest::prodNA(data.frame(a=c(1:100)),noNA=0.3))
$a
  [1]   1  NA   3  NA   5  NA   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  NA
 [21]  21  22  23  24  NA  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  NA  35  NA  37  38  39  40
 [41]  41  42  43  NA  45  46  47  48  NA  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  NA  NA  60
 [61]  61  62  NA  NA  65  66  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  74  75  NA  77  NA  79  NA
 [81]  81  82  NA  84  85  86  NA  88  89  90  91  92  NA  94  95  NA  NA  NA  NA 100
```

How can I get

```
> as.list(data.frame(a=c(1:100)))
$a
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 [21]  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
 [41]  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 [61]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
 [81]  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

by filling NA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zoo`'s `na.spline`

```
x <- missForest::prodNA(data.frame(a=c(1:100)),noNA=0.3)$a
zoo::na.spline(x)

#[1]    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
#[16]  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
#[31]  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
#[46]  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
#[61]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75
#[76]  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
#[91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```